# How to skip whitespaces for a character array?

Tags: c++, arrays, encryption, char, whitespace

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
char input[100],crypt[100],decrypt[100];
int key,key1[100],j=0,i;
cout << "Enter plaintxt:";
gets_s(input);
cout << "Enter key:";
cin >> key;
key1[0] = key;
for (int i = 1; i < strlen(input); i++){
    if (input[i - 1] >= 97 && input[i - 1] <= 122)
    key1[i] = ((int)input[i-1])-97;

}
for (int j = 0; j < strlen(input); j++){
    cout << key1[j]<<" ";
}
for ( i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++){
    crypt[i] = (char)((key1[i] + (int)(input[i]-97)) % 26+97);
}
crypt[i] = '\0';
cout << crypt;
//decrypt[0] = ((int)crypt[0] - 97)-key;
//cout << decrypt[0];
_getch();
}
```

my input is:attack is good,
my key is 12 and my output should be: mtmtcm sa ljrdy.....NOTE:
this is a type of monoalphabetic cipher

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue is just with the space character, calling this function after taking the user input will solve the issue as it will remove the spaces:

```
void RemoveSpaces(char* IN_cpSource)
{
if  (IN_cpSource == NULL)
    {
    exit(1);
    }
char* cpResult = IN_cpSource;

do
{
*cpResult = *IN_cpSource;

if  (*cpResult != ' ')
    {
    cpResult++;
    };
}while (*IN_cpSource++ != 0);
}
```